# Play Framework Entities connection

Tags: playframework, entity, models

this is a beginner question, I'm trying to work with play framework and I have a question I can't seem to figure out

Lets say I have classes A and B defined as

```
package models;
@Entity
public class A extends Model {
@Id
Long idA;
List<B> listofB;
etc..
}
```

and

```
package models;
@Entity
public class B extends Model {
@Id
Long idB;
etc..
}
```

I also have the finder class created in both classes

1. I want A to have multiple B's, and I want for them to be different, such as, I can have A with id 1 having B's with id 1 and 2, and A with id 2 having B's with id 1 and 2, these B's will all be different, how can I do that?
   I assume it's something related to @ManyToOne tags and such, but I can't figure out exactly how to do it
2. After that, I want to create a method such as

   ```
   public B getB(Long idA, Long idB) {
   ...
   }
   ```

   that can get me a specific B.
   How do I do this?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Good Day.

The database structure that you want to achieve is not achievable.
Your code

```
package models;
@Entity
public class A extends Model {
@Id
Long idA;
List<B> listofB;
etc..
}
```

and

```
package models;
@Entity
public class B extends Model {
@Id
Long idB;
etc..
}
```

REMEMBER that

```
@Id
```

will be your primary key.

Your question suggests that your idB is a primary key and should not have the same value..

To be able to achieve that you may want to do it this way,

```
package models;
@Entity
public class A extends Model {
@Id
Long idA;
List<B> listofB;
etc..
}
```

and

```
package models;
@Entity
public class B extends Model {
@Id
Long UID;

Long idB;
etc..
}
```

And last, on your second problem,
try this

```
 A a = A.find("idA = ?", someIdA).first();
 B b = a.A.find("idB = ?", someIdB).first();
```

Hope this answer helps you. :)